# Books were in short supply. (prepositional phrase)

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> Books were in short supply.

I wonder if the prepositional phrase 'in short supply' is an adverbial or adjectival phrase. And wonder whether the verb 'were' is used here to mean 'exist' like I '**am**' in the room..

Comment: It's neither adverbial nor adjectival. Your example has the idiomatic preposition phrase "in short supply" as **complement** of "be" (i.e. "were").

Comment: "nouns" and "adjectives" are used for complements after "be", then it is "adjectival phrase"?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? When you ask whether it's adjectival or adverbial, are you asking about what part of speech it is, or what it's function is in terms of its relationship to "Books"?

Comment: My question is crystal-clear. In "I am in the room.", "in the room" is an adverbial phrase. In the sentence "It is of importance.", "of importance" is an "adjectival phrase" which is used as complement of "be: is".

Comment: @BEBYGONES It's not just nouns and adjectives that can function as complements of "be" but many other kinds of expression too, such as clauses, preposition phrases and even adverbs!  "In" is a preposition so "in short supply" is a preposition phrase. Its function is that of complement of "be" (i.e. "were").